# Нужно ли при такой задаче объединить микросервисы в одно приложение?

Tags: архитектура, микросервисы

Есть два микросервиса:

1. Для управления пользователями и работы с структурой
   Таблица

```
user
id parentId login
```

Для работы с структурой используется SQL запрос:

```
with recursive cte as ( select id, 1 as depth from user where parentId = ${userId} union all select p.id, cte.depth + 1 from user p inner join cte on p.parentId = cte.id )
```

2. Для хранения данных об покупках пользователя

```
purchase
id userId amount
```

Задача:
В 1 микросервисе возвращать новый столбец `turnover` т.е это сумма всех покупок дочерних пользователей у которых стоит parentId пользователя.

Проблема в том что эти 2 микросервиса друг от други изолированы и делать на каждого пользователя запросы в отдельный микросервис выглядит не очень оптимизровано.

Проще всего мне кажется это добавить`inner join purchase` в этот рекурсивный запрос.

Вопрос: При изначальном проектировании архитектуры правильно было бы объединить эти две сущности в одно приложение или разместить таблицы в 1 базе данных?

P.S Это только тестовый проект для обучения микросервисов.

Comment: [читаем, думаем](https://tproger.ru/translations/you-dont-need-microservices/) и наверное приходим к выводу, что для обучения  микросервисам нужно что-то более близкое к ситуации, когда они приносят пользу

Comment: Суть вашей проблемы в декомпозиции на этапе, когда она еще не нужна. Ммкросервисная архитектура хороша, когда она действительно требуется, в ином случае, везде вы будете видеть только проблемы и оверхед. Попробуйте представить, что ваше приложение обросло десятками тысяч строк кода, что это будет за код и в какие логически независимые блоки он будет выделен, грубо говоря, это и могут быть ваши микросервисы. Микросервисы всегда будут нести на себе некий оверхед, как в вашем примере, однако, важно понимать, что это внутрекластерное взаимодействие без реального похода по сети.